# Passing array and checking if list is a part of array in c++

Tags: c++

I have stored values in array.  void MYArray stores the Id. Once this function stored all the Ids, I want to call this array to check whether a list is a part of this array or not. For example, list has elements/id {2,4,7} and array has elements/id {1,2,3,5,7,8}. how can I check whether the list a part of array?

```
int CopmareArray(Node* node, int x[]) // func prototype

int myarr[12];
int id=0;
int myid;

void MYArray(Node* node,........,int myarr[]){ 
............ // This function stores all the Ids in array
........... 
   {
     myid = nodeId;
     id++;
   }
   myarr[id] = myid;
} 

//This function takes the myarr[] as argument. Is this correct way to do so?  

 int CopmareArray(Node* node, int x[]) { 
 int a = 0,
 for (list<Node*>::iterator itr = Nodes.begin(); itr != Nodes.end(); ++itr){
 //here i want to call my array if this list is part of my array then I want to return a = 1 other wise 0. But i dont know how to do this.
```

Comment: So each Node in `Nodes` has a single int value?

Comment: Are you talking abt this  "for (list<Node*>::iterator itr = Nodes.begin(); itr != Nodes.end(); ++itr)"? Its a list containing ids let say {2, 3,5}. no duplicate id.

Comment: I provided you with a design. Please provide a [MCVE]. We don't know how your list was declared. You sould use a `std::vector` instead of `list` where `list` in c++ does not accurately mean its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you will need to declare a bool (or an int as you desired) and then initialize it as true (or the 1). Then you will need to iterate your `Nodes` for each value in `int x[]`, once one of the values in `int x[]` is not in `Nodes` then you will change that bool to `false` (or 0). Once the iteration of `int x[]` is finishes, you return that bool ( or the int).

You can do it this way:

```
bool YourBoolHere = true; // or int = 1
for( unsigned int xElement = 0; a < sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]); xElement = xElement + 1 )
{
    for (list<Node*>::iterator itr = Nodes.begin(); itr != Nodes.end(); ++itr)
    {
        if(x[xElement] != itr->YourInNodeValueHere)
            YourBoolHere = false; // or 0
    }
}

return YourBoolHere;
```

Comment: I had tried it like this bcz I have to check if list is subset of array then return true or 1.....but my array is not being called. I have used cout but it always show me 0.  for (list<Node*>::iterator itr = Nodes.begin(); itr != Nodes.end(); ++itr){
       for (unsigned int j=0; j<sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]); j++){  
     if((*itr)->Id != x[j])
    cout<<" ID "<<(*itr)->Id<<"print array "<<x[j]<<endl;  return a = 0;
   } 
     
 } return r = 1;
}

Comment: I am sorry I mis confused `validate list in the array` with `validate array in the list`. I don't have a compiler now but you have the idea. What value of x do you see when you debug and step over your loops? Or give me some time

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me. Actually I had tried this code but I was unsure about it that whether this is right or not that's why I posted my question here. If list {2,3,4} is in array {1, 2,3, 4,5 ,7} then return true. Second thing about x, it always show me 0. Although  **void MYArray** is storing the values. I think there is an issue with taking array as an argument.

Comment: Glad we are able to help :) But could you please provide all the codes?? [MCVE]?

Comment: ' int CopmareArray(Node* node, int x[]) // func prototype

int myarr[12];
int id=0;
int myid;

void MYArray(Node* node,........,int myarr[]){ 
............ // This function stores all the Ids in array
........... 
   {
     myid = nodeId;
     id++;
   }
   myarr[id] = myid;
} '

Comment: above one is an array function to store all the ids

Comment: `int CopmareArray(Node* node, int x[])
{ 
int a = 0,
for (list<Node*>::iterator itr = Nodes.begin(); itr != Nodes.end(); ++itr){ for (unsigned int j=0; j<sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]); j++){ if((*itr)->Id != x[j]) cout<<" ID "<<(*itr)->Id<<"print array "<<x[j]<<endl; return a = 0; } } return r = 1; }`

Comment: The above one is to check if list is in array. but cout<<"print array "<<x[j] is always zero